# Android: Not able to change image in Window Title

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a parent activity (from which all other activities extend) -  with a 'Navigation Drawer Toggle' icon in window title.

I want to change the 'Navigation Drawer Toggle' image everytime drawer icon is clicked ( to open/close drawer)

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView imgDrawer;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    setContentView(R.layout.window_title);  
    imgDrawer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgdrawer);
    ...
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.window_title);
}

...
public void openDrawer()
{
  ...
   //Switch Image
   imgDrawer.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_close_drawer));
}

public void closeDrawer()
{
   ...
   //Switch Image
   imgDrawer.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_open_drawer));
}
...
}
```

*Problem is that the 'imgDrawer' is not changing, when openDrawer and closeDrawer is invoked.
Is this becz the 'imgDrawer' icon is in window title or something else?*

Comment: set this before onCreate....getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.window_title);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `setContentView` and `setFeatureInt` layout is same and calling `getWindow().setFeatureInt` before setting layout for Title. do it as:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    setContentView(R.layout.window_title);  

    ...
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.window_title);
    imgDrawer = (ImageView)getWindow().findViewById(R.id.imgdrawer);
}
```

or pass a layout which contain ImageView with different is from `setContentView` layout